# Using Team Foundation Server with limited Windows user accounts

Tags: tfs

I'm gonna add new users to Windows solely for the purpose of being used for TFS. These accounts will be as limited as they can. The question is will this be a problem for TFS? I mean will this limited Windows accounts prevent users to do certain things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Not a problem at all.  All of the access operates at the service account level.